# PHPWord how to text break inside table cell?

Tags: php, phpword

I currently have big dificulties for put some text properly inside a cell from a table.
I would like the text to be like this : 
"Analyse from computer
computername"

And it is displaying like this inside the cell : 
"Analyse from computer computername"

Here is my current code :

```
$table = $section->addTable('myTable');

$table->addRow(300);
$table->addCell(4000)->addImage('logo_sat.png',array ('width'=>100,'align'=>'center'));
$table->addCell(6400, $styleVertical)->addText("Analyse from computer \n $computername", $styleFirstHeader, $styleCenter);
$table->addCell(4000, $styleVertical)->addText("SAT" , $styleFirstHeader, $styleCenter);
$table->addRow(30);
$table->addCell(4000, $styleVertical)->addText("ADR $chantier_code/$analyse_id" , $styleFirstHeader, $styleCenter);
$table->addCell(5200, $styleVertical)->addText("Indice : $indice  Date : $analyse_datemaj " , $styleFirstHeader, $styleCenter);
$table->addCell(5200, $styleVertical)->addText("Page : " , $styleFirstHeader, $styleCenter);
```

I have seen `$section->addTextBreak([$breakCount], [$fontStyle], [$paragraphStyle]);`
inside the documentation but it seems not compatible with a table cell.

Any idea how we could make this works?

Comment: Have you tried adding `CHAR(10)` (the Enter key) ?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I added it at the place of \n and It simply write CHAR(10)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way, but this is how I got it to work.

```
$table->addRow(300, $rowStyle);
  $cell = $table->addCell(4000, $cellStyle);
    $cell->addText('some text', $textStyle);
    $cell->addText('more text', $textStyle);
```